# Modifying Joomla Main Menu's submenu using template override

Tags: templates, joomla, overriding

I would like to achieve the following in my Joomla template's main menu:

```
    <ul class="topmenu">
         <li><a class="nav_link" id="active" href="#">Home</a></li><span class="separator"></span>
         <li><a class="nav_link" href="#">About Us</a></li><span class="separator"></span>
         <li><a class="nav_link" href="#">Services</a>
<div class="subnav_wrapper">
      <ul class="subnav">
       <li><a class="sub_nav_link" href="#">Custom Software</a></li>
       <li><a class="sub_nav_link" href="#">Software Solutions</a></li>
       <li><a class="sub_nav_link" href="#">Mobile SMS</a></li>
       <li><a class="sub_nav_link" href="#">Web Solutions</a></li>
       <li class="last"><a class="sub_nav_link" href="#">ICT Consultancy</a></li>
      </ul>
      </div>
     </li><span class="separator"></span>
</ul>
```

I've already overriden the default.php file for the module (I've copied "default.php" from "modules\mod_mainmenu\tmpl" into "templates\mytemplate\html\mod_mainmenu". What I don't get is how I can differentiate between the top-level ul, li and a elements and those in the subnav. For example, to add the class "last" to the last list item in the subnav, I've tried the following:

```
if ($node->name() == 'ul') {
   foreach ($node->children() as $child)
   {
    if ($child->attributes('access') > $user->get('aid', 0)) {
     $node->removeChild($child);
    }
   }
   $children_count = count($node->children());
   $children_index = 0;
   foreach ($node->children() as $child) {
   if ($children_index == $children_count - 1) {
    $child->addAttribute('class', 'last');
   }
   $children_index++;
   }

 }
```

But the above adds the class also in the last item of the top-level ul.

Is a way to achieve the desired effect using the template override method?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the template overriding of menus. You could look at http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/structure-a-navigation/menu-systems/tree-menus/163 which is a great module for customising menus.

Alternatively, if you want to merely style the menu items you could look into using ul li:last-child in your CSS. Note this is not fully supported across all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

For appointment a `last` and `first` classes to the last and first items of branches of the hierarchical menu in current 2.5.4 version of Joomla, I'm add to `default.php` (it's copied from `modules\mod_mainmenu\tmpl\` to `templates\mytemplate\html\mod_mainmenu\`) this code:

after:

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
```

insert:

```
$last_items = array();
foreach( array_reverse( $list, true ) as $v ) {
    if( ! isset( $last_items[$v->parent_id] ) )
        $last_items[$v->parent_id] = $v->id;
}
$first_start = true;
```

and replace:

```
if ($item->deeper) {
    $class .= ' deeper';
}
```

with:

```
if( $first_start ) {
    $class .= ' first';
    $first_start = false;
}
else if( in_array( $item->id, $last_items ) ) {
    $class .= ' last';
}

if ($item->deeper) {
    $class .= ' deeper';
    $first_start = true;
}
```

**There is the possibility of get rid of such as adding a** `last` **class in the last item of the top-level** `ul` – can be replaced:

```
else if( in_array( $item->id, $last_items ) ) {
    $class .= ' last';
}
```

with:

```
else if( in_array($item->id, $last_items) && $item->level_diff > 0 ) {
    $class .= ' last';
}
```